# Pointer-like behaviour in assignment operator when dealing with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, assignment-operator

I have stumbled across some strange behaviour of the assignment operator += that totally bogs me. See this code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

def myalg(data, alpha, beta):

    adash=np.zeros(len(data))
    a=np.zeros_like(adash)
    a_=np.zeros_like(a)
    gain=1
    count=0

    while count<3:
        adash=adash+alpha*np.gradient(data)
        a_old=a
        print( a_old)
        #a+=alpha* (np.gradient(adash)+ alpha* data)
        a=a+alpha* (np.gradient(adash)+  alpha* data)
        print( a_old)
        a/=1+alpha*beta
        #a=a/(1+alpha*beta)
        print( a_old)
        a_=2*a-a_old
        
        gain=la.norm(a-a_old)
        count+=1 
        print(a)
        print(a_)
        print(adash)
        print(gain)

data=np.arange(6)
myalg(data, alpha=0.4, beta=0.25)
```

I would have expected that nothing changes when exchanging one of 'comments' for the above alternative line. And while the `a`-array is indeed the same in each case, the code does change `a_old`:
When chosing `a=a+...`, `a_old` remains unchanged, no matter which one of `a/=` or `a=a/...` is chosen below.
When chosing the assignment operator `a+=`, `a_old` behaves like a "pointer" to `a`, however. So `print(a_old)` yields the value of `a` each time it is called until `a` is assigned a new value explicitely (e. g. `a= a/...`,instead of an assignment operator like `+=, -=, *=, /=`).

So why does this happen for arrays?

EDIT: I see HOW it happens, but I do not understand WHY this happens.
Why does this behaviour not occur for e.g. integers or floats?

Comment: You do `a_old = aprint(a_old)` but at this point `a_old` is not yet defined. This should result in an UnboundLocalError. Also what is `aprint`? Note that `a += ...` modifies an array in-place while `a = a + ...` creates a new copy.

Comment: I cannot see any `a*=...` or `a=a*...` in your code. The description is not clear to me.

Comment: `y=x` does not make copy.  `y` references the same object as `x`.  If `y` is mutated, you'll see the changes in `x` as well.  Numbers aren't mutatable, arrays (and lists) are.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comments on each line to see why the behavior is different (*Note*: indentation is for clarity purposes and not for coding):

```
#This points to `a`
a_old=a
print(a_old)

    #This changes `a` inplace so `a_old` will change too
    a+=alpha* (np.gradient(adash)+ alpha* data)
    
    #This creates a NEW `a`, therefore `a_old` will not change
    a=a+alpha* (np.gradient(adash)+  alpha* data)

print(a_old)

    #if you have used `a+=..` this changes `a` inplace again and so `a_old`
    #if you have used `a=a+..` this changes the NEW `a` and NOT the `a_old`
    a/=1+alpha*beta

    #this creates yet another NEWER `a` 
    #and hence `a_old` does not change beyond the LAST print
    a=a/(1+alpha*beta)

print(a_old)
```

Comment: Sorry for the */-confusion, I edited that for clarity. I have realised the process that leads to this behaviour, however I do not understand why this is not the case for other objects like floats/integers...

Comment: @Ehsan, I think you mean a float/int data type *never* changes inplace. Only mutable types (like arrays) can be changed inplace. Note that for a variable to be changed inplace, the `id()` of that variable (i.e. its location in memory) remains constant while the contents of the variable change.